# How to remove all elements of xml tag if they are duplicate [python]

Tags: python, xml, duplicates

I have an exemple of xml like this:

```
<annotation>
<folder>Test</folder>
<filename>10 2019-02-06_20-32.png</filename>
<source>
    <database>undefined</database>
</source>
<size>
    <width>768</width>
    <height>574</height>
    <depth>3</depth>
</size>
<segmented>0</segmented>
<object>
    <name>low</name>
    <pose>Left</pose>
    <truncated>0</truncated>
    <difficult>0</difficult>
    <bndbox>
        <xmin>360</xmin>
        <ymin>38</ymin>
        <xmax>434</xmax>
        <ymax>113</ymax>
    </bndbox>
</object>
<object>
    <name>medium</name>
    <pose>Left</pose>
    <truncated>0</truncated>
    <difficult>0</difficult>
    <bndbox>
        <xmin>227</xmin>
        <ymin>128</ymin>
        <xmax>290</xmax>
        <ymax>200</ymax>
    </bndbox>
</object>
<object>
    <name>low</name>
    <pose>Left</pose>
    <truncated>0</truncated>
    <difficult>0</difficult>
    <bndbox>                 //duplicate
        <xmin>360</xmin>
        <ymin>38</ymin>
        <xmax>434</xmax>
        <ymax>113</ymax>
    </bndbox>
</object>
<object>
    <name>medium</name>
    <pose>Left</pose>
    <truncated>0</truncated>
    <difficult>0</difficult>
    <bndbox>                     //duplicate
        <xmin>227</xmin>
        <ymin>128</ymin>
        <xmax>290</xmax>
        <ymax>200</ymax>
    </bndbox>
</object>
```

In this example you can see two elements duplicated, How can I remove all "object" element corresponding to the duplicate element?

how can I detect if a duplicate is present?
the moment I find it how can I delete it?

Thanks for answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use BeautifulSoup and `extract()` method:

```
data = '''<annotation>
<folder>Test</folder>
<filename>10 2019-02-06_20-32.png</filename>
<source>
    <database>undefined</database>
</source>
<size>
    <width>768</width>
    <height>574</height>
    <depth>3</depth>
</size>
<segmented>0</segmented>
<object>
    <name>low</name>
    <pose>Left</pose>
    <truncated>0</truncated>
    <difficult>0</difficult>
    <bndbox>
        <xmin>360</xmin>
        <ymin>38</ymin>
        <xmax>434</xmax>
        <ymax>113</ymax>
    </bndbox>
</object>
<object>
    <name>medium</name>
    <pose>Left</pose>
    <truncated>0</truncated>
    <difficult>0</difficult>
    <bndbox>
        <xmin>227</xmin>
        <ymin>128</ymin>
        <xmax>290</xmax>
        <ymax>200</ymax>
    </bndbox>
</object>
<object>
    <name>low</name>
    <pose>Left</pose>
    <truncated>0</truncated>
    <difficult>0</difficult>
    <bndbox>
        <xmin>360</xmin>
        <ymin>38</ymin>
        <xmax>434</xmax>
        <ymax>113</ymax>
    </bndbox>
</object>
<object>
    <name>medium</name>
    <pose>Left</pose>
    <truncated>0</truncated>
    <difficult>0</difficult>
    <bndbox>
        <xmin>227</xmin>
        <ymin>128</ymin>
        <xmax>290</xmax>
        <ymax>200</ymax>
    </bndbox>
</object>
</annotation>'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')

seen = set()
for obj in soup.select('object'):
    if obj not in seen:
        seen.add(obj)
        continue
    obj.extract()

print(soup)
```

Prints:

```
<annotation>
<folder>Test</folder>
<filename>10 2019-02-06_20-32.png</filename>
<source/>
<database>undefined</database>
<size>
<width>768</width>
<height>574</height>
<depth>3</depth>
</size>
<segmented>0</segmented>
<object>
<name>low</name>
<pose>Left</pose>
<truncated>0</truncated>
<difficult>0</difficult>
<bndbox>
<xmin>360</xmin>
<ymin>38</ymin>
<xmax>434</xmax>
<ymax>113</ymax>
</bndbox>
</object>
<object>
<name>medium</name>
<pose>Left</pose>
<truncated>0</truncated>
<difficult>0</difficult>
<bndbox>
<xmin>227</xmin>
<ymin>128</ymin>
<xmax>290</xmax>
<ymax>200</ymax>
</bndbox>
</object>


</annotation>
```